# How to query multiple tables at a time?

Tags: python, sql, django

**What I have**

I have an app, that archives tournaments in the game of chess. The app includes the following models:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

# Abstract base class
class Match(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    playerA = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='%(class)s_A') # eg. mastertournament_A
    playerB = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='%(class)s_B')
    score = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True 

# here are tables of ``Match`` instances played out in a particular 
# tournaments. All ``Match`` instances share the same fields 
# so, I could also have one big table for all matches but I want to keep 
# each Tournament in separate table for easiness.
class MasterTournament(Match):
    pass  

class AmateurTournament(Match):
    pass
```

Now, I plan to have two different views: `tournament_view` (lists all matches played in a tournament) and `player_view` (lists all matches a player played throughout all tournaments)

**Problem to solve**

Given the views I mentioned, I need to perform two different queries for each.
In a `tournament_view` I will have filters (Choice Filter) `playerA` and `playerB` and I need to dynamically populate choices for them. This can easily be done with:

```
playersA_all = MasterTournament.objects.value_list('playerA')
playersB_all = MasterTournament.objects.value_list('playerB')
```

However, I am struggling to come up with the query for `player_view`. This view is very similar with Choice Filters `playerA` and `playerB` but now, for the choices I need to query all Tournament tables to get all opponents of the player who is being viewed. This will result in a bunch of database hits each time and in the process I'll need to introduce a temporary list to save and append results from different tables.

That's why I am feeling like I need to reorganize my models, but the only solution that comes to my mind is to have that huge one table with all tournaments' matches packed together, something I wanted to prevent from happening.

My question is, do you have any ideas how to tweak my models, or perhaps django does provide a solution to perform the query I need for `player_view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two ForeignKey fields, have one ManyToMany Field:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through='Participate')
    score = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Participate(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match)
    visitor = models.BooleanField()
```

I think it solves most of your problem, and also makes a lot more sense, since there's no point in defining one as A and one is B. Both are players, there's nothing exceptionally distinguishable between them.

Comment: +1, I am not yet accepting because, I didn't mention it but playerA means kind of a `player_at_home` and `playerB` is a `visitor`. I didn't think it was important but I actually want to distinguish between players, I might need that. Do you think your solution will prevail under these news?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to use an intermediary table for it using 'through'. Read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

Comment: @nutship ManyToMany is one extra table and extra query. With one table you will get -2 queries without any efforts! think about it

Comment: @ndpu, I understand but say, with 20k+ matches one table might get a mess and slow down the querying?

Comment: @nutship 10k or 100M matches its ok, just add limit and number of rows in result depend on query parameters. And if in result you need information from both tables - you need to union results in the end

Answer (score 2):

I've actually done something like this before, though I wasn't using Django to do it. The concept of getting all the opponents is a problem when the number of matches gets large. I was able to leverage my solution to also keep track of wins and losses, without having to calculate on the fly.

See www.eurosportscoreboard.com.

Anyway, the way I solved it was with triggers. You could do the same with a save signal.

Create an `Opponent` model with a fk relationship with `Player` and `Match`. When a `Match` is saved, create an `Opponent` for each player. The write will be a little slow, but the reads will be very fast.

Comment: @nutship what Rob is describing is exactly how a 'through' ManyToMany works in django.

Comment: Thanks guys for clearing this up for me cuz Ive been really suffering in figuring this out on my own!

Comment: Also, I think you should really think about `Amateur` and `Master` being separate models. Why not have `Tournament.type = models.ForeignKey(TournamentType)`? It will be way more flexible. In the future, your client may add a ProAm tournament, or something.

Comment: These master and amateur examples are not types, these are names of a tournament (I might have named them misleadingly). That said, there will be like 10 tournaments and counting. Do you think your advise is still valid for this big number of tournaments?

Comment: Yes, in fact, the more tournaments you have, the more valid it is. You don't want to make a new table or model for each tournament. It will slow everything down. Think about it: Every time there's a new tournament, you'll have to run syncdb or migrate to create a new table. Why not just give each tournament a name?

Comment: So basically, what you're saying is to keep all the records in one table? like this: http://paste.ofcode.org/gZZY2crnkRbAip8tDzzLf8 ; I thought (intuitively, did not make any benchmarks) that separate tables (with each having less rows) instead of one big will be faster.

Comment: I'll add that using abstract models can be useful if you need different tables with a few core similarities. In your case, Rob is absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

**You cant query multiple tables at a time!** You can make several queries and union results.

```
# so, I could also have one big table for all matches but I want to keep 
# each Tournament in separate table for easiness.
```

This is a bad decision in case if you will need information from both tables in query results. Think about how you will query (with 2 tables) for one tournamet matches or positive score matches or matches with specific players - you must do queries to 2 tables and union results that doubles DB load. In this case you should create one table for matches, i think, and make one field for match type - Master or Amauter:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    playerA = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='%(class)s_A') # eg. mastertournament_A
    playerB = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='%(class)s_B')
    score = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    master_or_amauter = models.BooleanField(default=True) # master by default
```

And with one table you have no problem in player_view...

Comment: -1. Sorry, but this is a bad answer. It doesn't really answer the question, and you're also wrong, there's nothing really bad about his design. If what he showed is all there is, then yeah, you're probably right. But the concept of using abstract models means that he can add additional fields for each of the child models that would be specific for its own type. That's not necessarily a bad decision

Comment: @ndpu, what happens if I have +10 tournaments? I think I do need to have different tables for each.

Comment: You're essentially right but I still hold that your answer is not a very good one