# DJANGO: How to query multiple tables, equal model without looping

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a nice way to query(DJANGO) temporal data, which is stored in different tables, but share the same model. Here's an example data model:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    x = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "24-01-2017"
```

Now, I could of course loop over the different days, changing _meta.db_table for every iteration, but there should be a way to do this in a single query in DJANGO. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables) doesn't seem to be it, as DJANGO develops [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123561/how-to-query-multiple-tables-at-a-time) may be outdated and I don't see anything related in the documentation.

How to handle this neatly?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**

Hm, probably I'm just looking for a way to perform a outer join... But I can't find any implementation for this.

Comment: I understand there might be a business usecase, but I would keep it simple and extensible - You could have a backup database table which holds historical data (along with a date field ofcourse), and the current table would hold the latest data, or the data you are interested in. That way, your model would consistently yield the same underlying database table.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is with physical data, the tables(MySQL) are multiple GB's per in size. We cannot determine which data we're interested in by tomorrow, so somehow we need to query multiple tables per query.